# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Поставил тире, а потом засомневался: "Тут что-то другое нужно, а что (—) не соображу".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно. Тире ставится, так как предложение неполное, пропущено слово "нужно", вместо него - тире.

Answer (score 0):

Тире можно не ставить. В неполных предложениях с пропущенным членом, который восстанавливается из предыдущей части, тире на месте пропуска факультативно.

Comment: В неполных предложениях с паузами всё также строго, как и в теме "тире между подлежащим и сказуемым": есть пауза - есть тире. Это предложение без паузы не произносится -  следовательно, постановка тире обязательна.

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что здесь пауза обязательна? Я произношу без паузы. И большинство людей, если прислушаться к спонтанной речи, паузу не делают. Можно где-то почитать об обязательности пауз при пропуске члена? Каков критерий "объективной" паузы? Действительно интересно.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего, мы для себя должны различать спонтанную (устную) речь и озвученное письмо. Устная речь имеет свои законы (например, существуют специальные монографии, посвященные синтаксису устной речи), она во многом зависит от темпа произношения и др.

Перед тем, как записать предложение, мы медленно и выразительно произносим его ЗВУКОВОЙ ВАРИАНТ(безо всякой спонтанности), чтобы определить  интонационную структуру. Пауза - только часть интонации, очень важно обозначить понижение или повышение  тона.

В нашем случае это выглядит так: "Тут что-то другое нужно (пауза, повышение тона, а что (пауза, повышение тона  - не соображу (понижение тона)". Таким образом, предложение состоит из трех фраз: повышение тона, повышение тона, понижение тона.

Такую же интонацию имеет соответствующее полное предложение: "Тут что-то другое нужно, а что именно нужно — не соображу". По структуре это простое  предложение + СПП. Получается, что в неполном варианте мы убрали повтор, но сохранили исходную структуру.

Если  мы не поставим тире, то предложение будет состоять из двух фраз: "Тут что-то другое нужно (повышение тона), а что не соображу (понижение тона)". Такая структура отлична от исходного полного предложения, вторая часть вообще "не читается" (не укладывается в одну фразу), смысл сообщения угадывается с трудом.